# How do I make all child views of a layout resize/change position to make my TableLayout fill the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout, android-design-library, android-fonts

It doesn't have to necessarily resize the child views, it just has fit the screen, not hide some views in the layout and not leave ugly space on the screen.

**fragment_timetable.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".timetable.TimetableFragment">

    <include layout="@layout/fragment_timetable_login" />

    <include layout="@layout/fragment_timetable_table" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_timetable_table.xml (Github link because exceeds the character limit):**
https://github.com/gogobebe2/TheDayAhead/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_timetable_table.xml

*Here is all of the code (probably not relevant): https://github.com/gogobebe2/TheDayAhead*

As you can see, the font size and all other child views in the `TableLayout` are too big to fit on the screen:
[image: As you can see, the font size and all other child views in the <code>TableLayout</code> are too big to fit on the screen]

And if the screen is bigger, it's too small and doesn't fill the screen:
[image: And if the screen is bigger, it's too small and doesn't fill the screen]

Comment: If you downvote my question, please explain why or give suggestions on how I can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. All I needed to do was add `android:weightSum="11"` to `<TableLayout >` and add `android:layout_weight="1"` to each `<TableRow >`.